# Native Base Tab Bar issue - react native

Tags: react-native, tabs, native-base

My project uses native base 3.2.0. Trying to import tabs from native base fails with the following error:

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in."**

My code is :

> *<Tab heading={ No
> Ifcon}>
>
>
> <Tab heading={ No Icon}>*

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

into `{}` set default value if your props can be `null`.
exp :

```js
<Tab heading={value || ""}/>
```

Comment: I tried with static value. It is still same.

Comment: try to use other components or code ```Tab``` manually. you can see in [NativeBase repo](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/index.tsx) doesn't export ```Tab``` component.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: you can use [react-native-tab-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) or handle it manually with ```Flatlist```

Comment: Already tried react-native-tab-view. It throws same error